# Sample Color tool. Eyedropper reverts to a pointer

Tags: node-editor, shaders, color, error

In the Shader editor if I click to change the colour in one of the colour swatch windows on a Principled node and then select the eyedropper or Colour Sample tool, as soon as I move the mouse it reverts to a pointer and won't allow me to select a colour from an adjacent Image Editor window.

See the gif below, it's a little difficult to describe.

[image]

Comment: This is not how it's supposed to work. The cursor should remain the eyedropper until you've made the selection. What version of Blender are you using and on which OS?

Comment: Hi Robert, thank you, yes one would expect the cursor to remain an eyedropper as you say, until the selection is complete. But it still functions as it should. I'm running Blender 2.91.0 on Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6. In the past with older Blender versions I recall a similar issue some times, but my memory may not be correct.

Comment: Could you please check if [2.91.2](https://www.blender.org/download/) has solved this problem and report it on the bug tracker otherwise (*Help > Report a Bug* in Blender)?

Answer (score 4):

I've worked it out, it's not an error after all. Once you select the Eyedropper, when you move the mouse the cursor will revert to a pointer, however the next click will change the color wherever you click in the Blender window. Just not immediately intuitive because the cursor doesn't remain as a pipette.